# $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\ln(x^3)}{x^2-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

My first idea was to use the definition of derivative (but it's giving me the wrong answer).

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\ln(x^3)}{x^2-1} =\lim_{t \to 1}\frac{\ln(t^{3/2})}{t-1} = \frac{3}{2}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln(t+1)}{t} =\frac{3}{2}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln(t+1)-\ln(1)}{t} = \frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)\bigg|_{x=1} = 0.$

But using L'hopital's rule I get $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\ln(x^3)}{x^2-1} =\frac{3\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)}{\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-1)} = \frac{3}{2}\lim_{x \to 1}\frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{3}{2}.$

So where have I messed up in the first approach?

Comment: You have forgotten $\frac{3}{2}$ and do $x=1$ !!!after!!! derivating.

Comment: Wow! Simply shows that I need to spend more time on questions before posting them in here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your error is that

$$\frac{d}{dx} \ln x \big|_{x = 1} = \frac 1 x \big|_{x = 1} = 1$$

---

Here's a slightly different way that doesn't involve making a substitution before applying the definition of the derivative:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\ln(x^3)}{x^2 - 1} &= \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{3}{x + 1} \frac{\ln x}{x - 1} \\
&= \frac{3}{1 + 1} \frac{d}{dx} \ln x \big|_{x = 1} \\
&= \frac 3 2
\end{align*}

as desired.

Answer (score 3):

$\log x^3 = 3 \log x \sim 3(x-1)$ as $x \to 1$ using Maclaurin series

Comment: $\log x = - \log \frac{1}{1-(1-x)} \sim -(1-x) = x-1$, so you are right

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$ \frac{3}{2} \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\ln(t + 1) - \ln(1)}{t} = \frac{3}{2} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \ln(x) \vert_{x = 1} = \frac{3}{2}.$$

You forgot the constant factor and $(\ln(x))' = \frac{1}{x}$ evaluated at $x = 1$ is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)\bigg|_{x=1} = \left.\frac1x\right|_{x=1}=1.
$$